# Como criar um loop infinito em um Carousel?

Tags: javascript, css

Bom, estou criando um Carousel, mas chegou a um ponto no qual eu travei por não saber como fazer, preciso criar um loop infinito entre os itens dentro do carousel, como posso realizar isso ?

Segue o código criado até agora

JS

```
function carousels(){

        //Capturar os carousels na page
        var carousels = document.querySelectorAll(".carousel");
        //Captura tamanho da tela
        var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
        //Abrir função para cada um
        for(var iCarousels = 0; iCarousels < carousels.length; iCarousels++){
            var bannersIn = carousels[iCarousels].querySelectorAll("figure");
            carousels[iCarousels].style.width = bannersIn.length * windowWidth + "px";
            for(var iBannersIn = 0; iBannersIn < bannersIn.length; iBannersIn++){
                bannersIn[iBannersIn].style.width = windowWidth + "px";
            }
            setInterval(function(){

            }, 2000)
        }
    }carousels();
```

CSS

```
.banner-holder {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.banner-holder .carousel {
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    display:flex;
    transition:all 1s ease-out;
}
.banner-holder .carousel figure {
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:100%;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
}
.banner-holder .carousel img {
    min-width:100%;
   position:absolute;
   height:100%;
   left:50%;
   top:50%;
   transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="banner-holder">
        <div class="carousel">
            <figure>
                <img src="assets/site/banners/banners_00.jpg">
                <figcaption>

                </figcaption>
            </figure>
            <figure>
                <img src="assets/site/banners/banners_01.jpg">
                <figcaption>

                </figcaption>
            </figure>
            <figure>
                <img src="assets/site/banners/banners_02.jpg">
                <figcaption>

                </figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Não consegue colocar o código rodando no snippet?

Comment: Não sei por snippet :/

Answer (score -2):

Ao final de todas operações que ocorrem dentro do loop, verifique se o valor do carrousel atual é maior que o lenght total, se for, basta zerar o valor atual para que ele não encerre o looping.

EIDT:

Imagino que o uso da função setInterval() seja para dar o delay entre uma imagem e outra, não necessitando que seja repetida a cada 2000ms, no Javascript existe a função similar, a setTimeout(), a diferença é que ela aguarda o tempo para executar a ação, e a executa apenas uma vez.
Mudei a comparação do seu for para que o if no inicio funcionasse sem a necessidade de decrementar o lenght.

```
function carousels(){
    //Capturar os carousels na page
    var carousels = document.querySelectorAll(".carousel");
    //Captura tamanho da tela
    var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
    //Abrir função para cada um
    for(var iCarousels = 0; iCarousels <= carousels.length; iCarousels++){
        if(iCarousels == carousels.length){
            iCarousels = 0;
        }
        var bannersIn = carousels[iCarousels].querySelectorAll("figure");
        carousels[iCarousels].style.width = bannersIn.length * windowWidth + "px";
        for(var iBannersIn = 0; iBannersIn < bannersIn.length; iBannersIn++){
            bannersIn[iBannersIn].style.width = windowWidth + "px";
        }
        //setInterval(function(){}, 2000)
        setTimeout(function(){}, 2000);
    }
}carousels();
```